# Authenticate with a private key

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, key-authentication

Is it possible to authenticate myself with the private key at the public key?

The scenario: I gave another company the public key so that I can authenticate myself with my private key at the sftp server.

Is this "backwards asymmetric encryption" possible?
If not, can someone explain why?

Comment: *"I gave another company the public key so I can authenticate myself with my private key at the sftp server"* - That's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *always* put the public key on the remote server you want to login to.  The private key is meant to remain private to you.

So, with ssh, you put the public key into the `authorized_keys` file on the server you want to login to (or have the admin do it, if you don't have the ability yourself).

Now you can use the private key to access that remote server.

In general, you shouldn't give your private key to anyone; that's why it's called private.

Answer (score 0):

**Generalized and Simplified Public Key Authentication**

Asymmetric key pairs used for authentication are mathematically designed so as to be difficult to compute the private key using the public key.  This means one can effectively distribute the public key to anyone. The private key is used to generate a cryptographic token by the client which is verified using the public key on the server.

Since the whole point of authentication is to ensure that the entity attempting to be authenticated is the owner of the private key, the question is really moot.